# How can I create a 3D plot based on pixel intensity in Python?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, visualization

I have a TIF image, and based on its pixel intensity, I'm aiming to generate a 3D plot. I've come across a sample image that represents the kind of visualization I'm looking to achieve:

[image: 3D reconstruction sample]

Please note that the above image is just a sample. My goal is to produce a plot similar plot.Your support will be appreciated.

Comment: that is not image processing. that is not "3d reconstruction". that is plotting. find a library for plotting.

Comment: Could you please suggest which library I should begin with?

Comment: welcome. [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer

I would advise against this kind of plot. It may look cool, but it gives no additional information compared to only drawing the heatmap in the bottom, actually it gives *less* information because a part of the heatmap is hidden. The 3d plot is not informative at all in the example.

### How to Achieve This Plot Using `matplotlib`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def create_example_file(filename: str) -> None:
    """Create an example image"""
    X = np.arange(-2.5 * np.pi, 3.5 * np.pi, 0.25)
    Y = np.arange(-2.5 * np.pi, 3.5 * np.pi, 0.25)
    
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    zz = ((np.sin(xx) + np.sin(yy)) + 2) * (255 / 4)
    Image.fromarray(zz.astype(np.uint8)).save(filename)


filename = 'image.tiff'
create_example_file(filename)

img = Image.open(filename)
X = np.arange(img.size[0])
Y = np.arange(img.size[1])

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
zz = np.array(img)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, cmap='viridis')
C = ax.contourf(xx, yy, zz, z_dir='z', offset=-300, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_zlim(-300, 255)
ax.set_xlabel('x-Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-Axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z-Axis')

fig.colorbar(C, ax=ax, fraction=0.02, pad=0.1)
fig.tight_layout()
```